# SPD workflow loop through multi-option loopup column

Tags: 2010, workflow

One of our users has a custom list with 50+ items which contain of a UID and a contact. In a different custom library they have a lookup field where users *must* select one or multiple items. Based on the items that they have selected, they want to send e-mails to the contacts as selected and automatically create items in a third custom list.

We have been `*granted*` the task to make this work, however we do not have access to the server itself and have only been granted Site Collection Administrator permissions. I've started building a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010, but am lacking any form of looping method.

Does anyone know a method of looping through the multi-lookup field, getting the values, and doing things with the values? I'd hate it to make 50+ checkboxes and having to explain them how to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just figured out a way to do it, after a lot of trying and error fixing.
For ease of explaining I've named the column that holds the content for the lookup "SourceList"

**Preparation**
1) Create a loop list, containing three columns: Title, cnt, LoopGUID
2) Create one entry with the title "Count", a cnt of 0 and the LoopGUID "idle"
3) Add a column "LoopGUID" to the SourceList and fill it with the default value "idle"

**Three looping workflows**
*Workflow #1*
4) Create a Workflow on the custom list that the users fill in containing the selection(s) that runs on creates and edits
4.1) If "Loop list:cnt" equals 0
4.1.1) Pause 5 minutes
4.2) If "Loop list:cnt" equals 0
4.2.1) Pause 5 minutes
4.3) If "Loop list:cnt" equals 0
Stop workflow
4.4) Update "Loop list", set cnt = 1, LoopGUID = CurrentItem:GUID where title equals "Count"

*Workflow #2*
5) Create a Workflow on the Loop list that runs on edits
5.0) Create a local variable (String) called LookupValidator
5.1) If CurrentItem:cnt > 0
5.1.1) Set LocalVariable:LookupValidator to SourceList:GUID, where SourceList:LoopGUID equals "idle"
5.1.2) If LocalVariable:LookupValidator is not empty
5.1.2.1) Update item in SourceList: SourceList:LoopGUID = CurrentItem:LoopGUID, where SourceList:LoopGUID equals "idle"

*Workflow #3*
6) Create a Workflow on the SourceList that runs on edits
6.0) Create a local variable named cnt (Number) and a local variable named LookupValidator (String)
6.1) Set LocalVariable:cnt to LoopList:cnt, where Title equals "Count"
6.2) Calculate LocalVariable:cnt plus 1 and store in LocalVariable:cnt
6.3) Update LoopList:cnt = LocalVariable:cnt, where Title equals "Count"
6.4) Pause for 1 minute
6.5) If LoopList:cnt equals LocalVariable:cnt
6.5.1) Update LoopList, set cnt = 0, GUID = "idle" where Title = "Count"

**One workflow to do what you want**
*Workflow #4*
7) Create a Workflow on the SourceList that runs on edits
7.1a) If CurrentItem:LoopGUID is not empty
7.1b) And CurrentItem:LoopGUID not equals "idle"
7.1.1) [Do your actions here]
7.1.2) Pause for 1 minute
7.1.3) Update CurrentItem:LoopGUID = "idle"

The pauses will make sure that the list is automatically reset when all changes are complete. The 3 times 5 minutes wait on Workflow #1 is to give the workflow multiple chances of going through the entire sequence before giving up, just in case more then one item is modified within 4 minutes.